# Openlayers 4 custom pop-up for a GeoJSON layer

Tags: openlayers, popup

I need to get popups showing for just a single feature layer (forest -- stored as a GeoJSON) as opposed to all in Openlayers. I currently have the below.

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: "map",
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }),
      new ol.layer.Vector({
        renderMode: 'image',
        style: forestStyle,
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
          url: '../data/forests.geojson',
          format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
        })
      })
    ]
  });
```

How do I go about this, please?

PS: I am using Bootstrap 3 and could do with solutions built around it too.

**EDIT (After Mike's response)**

```
    {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 1,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              22.9629863189914,
              40.8240755346776
            ],
            [
              22.9692602042389,
              40.8166598348136
            ],
            [
              22.9690134736772,
              40.8169316800029
            ],
            [
              22.9687847485475,
              40.81713616158
            ],
            [
              22.9682455495031,
              40.8176072482245
            ],
            [
              22.9679709332253,
              40.81774367484
            ],
            [
              22.9673630702601,
              40.8179212679431
            ],
            [
              22.967084992837,
              40.8182602865605
            ],
            [
              22.9667116917971,
              40.8188278348423
            ],
            [
              22.9664306019971,
              40.8193063705868
            ],
            [
              22.9663027287322,
              40.8196696271834
            ],
            [
              22.9661765887141,
              40.8199428509784
            ],
            [
              22.9648132221368,
              40.8217371937712
            ],
            [
              22.9632330867235,
              40.8238037050033
            ],
            [
              22.9629863189914,
              40.8240755346776
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "FID": 1,
        "OBJECTID": 119,
        "ID": "GR-4291",
        "Code_12": "131",
        "Remark": " ",
        "Area_ha": 95.6086248776,
        "Shape_Leng": 6533.9468799,
        "code00": 13,
        "Shape_Le_1": 6533.9468799,
        "Shape_Area": 956086.248776,
      }
    }    
  ]
}
```

`

// Above is the JSON

```
var forest = new ol.layer.Vector({
    renderMode: 'image',
    style: forestStyle,
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      url: '../data/forests.geojson',
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    })
  })

var element = document.getElementById('popup');

  var popup = new ol.Overlay({
    element: element,
    positioning: 'bottom-center',
    stopEvent: false,
    offset: [0, -50]
  });

  map.addOverlay(popup);

  map.on('click', function(evt) {
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
      function(feature) {
        return feature;
      },
      { layerFilter: function(candidate) { 
        return (candidate === forest)
      }
    });

    if (feature) {
      var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
      console.log(coordinates);
      popup.setPosition(coordinates);
      $(element).popover({
        'placement': 'top',
        'html': true,
        'content': feature.get('id')
      });
      $(element).popover('show');
    } else {
      $(element).popover('destroy');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the OpenLayer example https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/icon.html

Declare you forest layer separately so it can assigned to a variable, then add it to the map

```
var forestsLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        renderMode: 'image',
        style: forestStyle,
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
          url: '../data/forests.geojson',
          format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
        })
      });

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: "map",
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }),
      forestsLayer
    ]
  });
```

If you will be adding other layers and you are only interested in forests you should add a layer filter to the forEachFeatureAtPixel call

```
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
            function(feature) {
              return feature;
            },
            { layerFilter: function(candidate) { return (candidate === forestsLayer) } });
```

Note that the OpenLayers example wasn't written to handle multiple features, even on the same layer, and bootstrap doesn't always work as expected. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53947527/popup-with-multiple-points-features

Comment: Thank you! I have implemented your suggestion but still don't get any pop-up. My GeoJSON structure has been added to the original question as an edit. I also added popup to my HTML structure. I tried logging "coordinates" to my console and I see no output on click.

Code will also be added to my original post as there is a character limit here.

Comment: Can you see any features on the map?  The GeoJSON coordinates are LonLat but the map projection is presumably web mercator if you are using OSM?  (I can't see where you set the view).  If so the format line should be `format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'})`

Comment: My GeoJSON data all load perfectly. I am using Openlayers as basemap.

Here is my view:

`view: new ol.View({
      center: [2620719.951785553,4954495.299388555],
      zoom: 9.3
    })`

Coordinates now work (see below) as I missed a bracket but still no popup in sight.

`(11) [Array(4437), Array(42), Array(20), Array(38), Array(51), Array(40), Array(90), Array(60), Array(75), Array(36), Array(59)]`

Comment: I have now put in a full geometry property value possibly the issue is at feature.get() or the defined feature variable in itself. Thank you!

Comment: Unlike the example you have polygons instead of points, so using the feature coordinates for the popups won't work.  To show a popup where you clicked use `var coordinates = map.getCoordinateFromPixel(evt.pixel);` instead

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately this doesn't still work. Issue seems to be in this bloc at the moment.

`if (feature) {
      var coordinates = map.getCoordinateFromPixel(evt.pixel);
      console.log(coordinates);
      popup.setPosition(coordinates);
      $(element).popover({
        'placement': 'top',
        'html': true,
        'content': feature.get('type')
      });
      $(element).popover('show');
    } else {
      $(element).popover('destroy');
    }`

Seeing a popup in itself and the 'content' is missing.

Comment: `'type'` isn't a property of the feature.  Try something in the properties object in the json such as `feature.get('ID')` (it will be case sensitive)

Comment: This doesn't work too. Also tried `'content': feature.get('properties.ID')` and still no luck. Maybe there is a way to check if the popup is part of the DOM before this point and then debug why the element properties doesn't show up?

Comment: The same code works for me.  Demo using a forests.geojson with just the one feature from your example, and zooming in to it:  http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/geojson-popup.html  With multiple features you would need to destroy and recreate the popup if going directly from one forest to another.

Comment: Oh wow!  May I see the code you used. Possibly I am getting something wrong!

Comment: You can use view source on the demo

Comment: Oh dear. The pop-up has been up all along. Because my map has some settings, it was hidden at the bottom left hand corner of the map under a sidebar..

`#map { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}`

Comment: Fixed the positioning of popup. How do you achieve this "With multiple features you would need to destroy and recreate the popup if going directly from one forest to another" and this should resolve this post fully.

Comment: You will need to destroy the previous popup, set a short timeout for the destroy to complete, then create a new one, otherwise the content won't update.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53947527/popup-with-multiple-points-features